# liquibase - how to generate the sql script from the changelog after comparing two databases using java?

Tags: java, liquibase

I compared two databases with liquibase java API 3.3.2, then generated the changelog.xml file. Now, I want to generate the sql script that will update the target database.
here is my code:

```
Database database;
Database database2;
try {
    database = CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getClassLoader(), "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/loan", "postgres", "", "org.postgresql.Driver", null, null, false, false, null, null, null, null, null);
    database2=CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getClassLoader(), "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/loan2", "postgres", "", "org.postgresql.Driver", null, null, false, false, null, null, null, null, null);
    Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("", new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
    DiffResult result = liquibase.diff(database, database2, new CompareControl());
    DiffToChangeLog diffLog = new DiffToChangeLog(result, new DiffOutputControl());
    diffLog.print(System.out);
    //new DiffToReport(result, System.out).print();

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is how I did it, thanks to Steve donie :

```
        Database database;
    Database database2;
    try {
        database = CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getClassLoader(), "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/loan", "postgres", "", "org.postgresql.Driver", null, null, false, false, null, null, null, null, null);
        database2= CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getClassLoader(), "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/loan2", "postgres", "", "org.postgresql.Driver", null, null, false, false, null, null, null, null, null);

        // generate the changelog that contains the differences
        CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog("changelog.xml", database, database2, new DiffOutputControl(), null, null);

        // generate the sql script from the changeLog (without executing it)
        File sql = new File("output.sql");
        Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("changelog.xml", new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);
        liquibase.update("Update", new FileWriter(sql));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Does that work? If not, what problems are you seeing? Good questions have 3 things: 1 - what I did. 2 - what I expected to happen. 3 - what actually happened.

Comment: @SteveDonie this code outputs the changelog.xml that represents the diffrences found between the two databases, right ? but I dont't know how  to generate the sql script that will update the target database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to see what Liquibase itself does when run from the commandline. In that case, you would normally use the diffChangeLog command to create the changelog, and then run updateSQL to generate the SQL required to update the database. Looking at Liquibase source code for `liquibase.integration.commandline.Main`, I see that [what it does is to use the Liquibase.update() method](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/3.3.x/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/commandline/Main.java#L1057-L1058) with arguments that specify [a non-null output writer](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/3.3.x/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/Liquibase.java#L243-L267) (which is the file that the SQL will be saved to).

Comment: Thank you steve, that did the job :)